# How to use scp with recursion and file mask for multiple extensions?

Tags: bash, scp

I'm trying to recursively download a directory, but only files with certain extensions from it, while also maintaining the directory structure.

The command I'm using now is
`scp -rp user@address:"/path/to/directory/foo/*\.{jpg,mp4}" ~/local/directory/foo/`. Which a) requires me to create directory `foo` locally, and b) it only downloads files in the root directory (recursion doesn't work).

The command I used before this was `scp -rp user@address:"/path/to/directory/foo" ~/local/directory/`, which didn't have either of those problems, but downloads all the files I don't need as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with `scp`. You can either copy all files recursively or selected file types non-recursively. Note that you don't need to escape the `.`.

But you could use `rsync`:

```
rsync -avm --include='*/' --include='*.jpg' --include='*.mp4' --exclude='*'\
  user@address:/path/to/directory/foo ~/local/directory/
```

Options used:

- `-a` archive mode
- `-v` increase verbosity
- `-m` prune empty directories
- `--include='*/'` include subdirectories
- `--include='*.jpg'` include `*.jpg` files
- `--include='*.mp4'` include `*.mp4` files
- `--exclude='*'` exclude other file types